# R: Cannot run certain function after cleaning temporary directory

Tags: r, temporary-directory

I get the error:

```
Error in file(fn, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(fn, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpwh6Zih\raster\r_tmp_2020-05-
13_170601_12152_33882.gri': No such file or directory
```

When I run the following code in RStudio (1.2.5042):

```
raster.binair <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(aggregated.rasters)) 
for (i in 1:NROW(aggregated.rasters)) { 
+     clamped <- clamp(aggregated.rasters[[i]], upper=12, useValues=FALSE)
+     raster.binair[[i]] <- clamped
+   }
```

"aggregated.rasters" is a list of 96 rasters and when I separately run it, I get the correct list. I recently cleaned my temporary directory (accessed by **tempdir()**) and deleted the files in there. I suppose the part:

```
cannot open file 'C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpwh6Zih\raster\r_tmp_2020-05-
13_170601_12152_33882.gri': No such file or directory
```

is referring to this. I don't know what I did wrong here. Can I get these files back or work around this error?

Answer (score 0):

Files in the temp folder are deleted when an R session ends. So you should never count on them. You can run the code again, but if you want to permanently keep the results you need to write them elsewhere. Here are two options

Write many files

```
raster.binair <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(aggregated.rasters)) 
for (i in 1:NROW(aggregated.rasters)) { 
    f <- paste0("raster_", i)
    clamped <- clamp(aggregated.rasters[[i]], upper=12, useValues=FALSE, filename=f)
    raster.binair[[i]] <- clamped
}
```

Write a single file

```
raster.binair <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(aggregated.rasters)) 
for (i in 1:NROW(aggregated.rasters)) { 
    raster.binair[[i]]  <- clamp(aggregated.rasters[[i]], upper=12, useValues=FALSE)
} 
s <- stack(raster.binair)
s <- writeRaster(s, filename="mydata.tif")
```

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you a lot for your help. I tried your suggestion, but this does not solve my error. The file that cannot be found in the directory is not a file I want as output, nor the intermediate "clamped" file, so I don't know why this file needs to be called on. When I end my R session and run my full code in a new one, I still receive the same error.

Comment: It is hard to help as I cannot reproduce this. Can you make a small reproducible example? Perhaps you can show where and when exactly the error occurs (at i = 1?); how  is aggregated.raster created? Do you need to recreate those?

Comment: Dear Robert, it turned out to be some internal problem with my version of R. Since I started to get the error for all functions I was running in R, I removed and upgraded R again, and now it seems to work. Thank you very much for tackling the problem with me!